# How to get access to iterator of some type?

Tags: c++

I have some code:

```
#include "NodesEdgesTriangles.h"


Triangles Chain_Triangulation( const ListLimitations& input_list_limitations )
{
    Edges edges_of_planar_graph;
    for ( Const_It_ListLimitations location = input_list_limitations.begin(); location !=    input_list_limitations.end(); ++location )
        //ERROR LINE
        edges_of_planar_graph.insert( edges_of_planar_graph.end(), location->begin(), location->end() );

}
   Triangles chain_triangulation;

   return chain_triangulation;
}
```

Compiler give me error:

> error C2839: invalid return type 'std::list<_Ty> *const *' for overloaded 'operator ->'

Comment: Please reduce your code to a minimal self-contained example that reproduces the problem. Also point out on which line the error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `input_list_limitations` is a list of pointers to other lists. That means that the iterator "points" to a *pointer* to a list, so when you dereference the iterator (with unary `*` or `->`) you have a pointer and not an instance. You need to a double dereference to be able to call the `begin` and `end` functions, like

```
(*location)->begin()
```

Explanation:

`*location` dereferences the iterator, which give you a pointer to a `std::list`. Then the `->` operator is used to dereference the pointer.

Comment: which does method return const_iterator?

Comment: @user3706947 If you want to make sure you get a constant iterator, use [`cbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/begin) and [`cend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/end) instead.

Comment: are you sure, that this container contains these methods? i cannot to find them

Comment: @user3706947 I was wrong, the error is actually something else, updated my answer.

Comment: rbegin rend is included in c++11